# open org-agenda weekly view window when emacs is loaded

Tags: elisp

I understand that `find-file "file path"` in .emacs can load the file automatically after emacs starts up.
However, I would like to have`org-agenda week` `C-c a a` open instead of a local file.
How can this be achieved by elisp?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `(org-agenda-list)` or `(execute-kbd-macro (kbd "C-c a a"))`, for example:

```lisp
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook #'org-agenda-list)
```

or

```lisp
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
          (lambda () (execute-kbd-macro (kbd "C-c a a"))))
```

Comment: Rather than using `execute-keyboard-macro` you can use `(org-agenda nil "a")` to open whatever agenda has shortcut "a".  This will work even if `C-a a` isn't bound to `org-agenda`.